# Amcharts chart stays visible after scrolling past boundaries of parent div

Tags: html, amcharts

I have a series of charts using the Amcharts javascript library on a page of my website. They are contained within a div that is bordered by a fixed header on the top and a fixed footer on the bottom, so the div has top and bottom edges that aren't at the edges of the page. I'm having a problem where when this central div containing the graphs is scrolled, going behind the header as it does so, the graphs continue to be visible above the header despite being inside the same div that is correctly going behind the header.

This ONLY happens with the graphs themselves. The rest of the elements, which include drop down selectors and horizontal rules, scroll correctly and go behind the header. Also, the individual divs that contain the graphs themselves do scroll correctly, it is just the Amcharts generated graph elements that I have no control over that don't scroll properly. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed? See the photo below, where the red box containing the graph scrolls correctly behind the header but the graph stays on top of it.

[image: image showing incorrect scrolling of Amcharts graph]

I'm not quite sure what code to include, as it seems to me that the problem is something to do with Amcharts, so here's the code that sets up the graph:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("vDataGraphs_AmbientTemperature", {
      "type": "serial",
            "dataLoader": {
        "url": "retrieve/getReportsForDate.php?date=2017-01-01"
      },

      "theme": "default",
      "plotAreaFillAlphas": 1,
                "plotAreaFillColors": "white",
      "autoMargins": false,
      "marginTop": 25,
                "marginRight": 0,
      "marginBottom": 20,
      "marginLeft": 44,

      "categoryField": "timestamp",
      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN",
            "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
                "minPeriod": "ss",
        "tickLength": 6,
        "centerLabels": true,
        "labelOffset": -3
            },

      "allLabels": [{
        "text": "Ambient Temperature so far Today",
        "align": "center",
        "bold": true,
        "size": 18,
        "y": -5
      }],
        "chartCursor": {
        "enabled": true,
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN",
        "cursorColor": "#000000",
        "fullWidth": true,
        "graphBulletSize": 0,
        "selectionAlpha": 0.3
      },
      "balloon": {
        "horizontalPadding": 9,
        "pointerWidth": 15,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
      },
      "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "horizontalGap": 22,
        "left": 0,
        "rollOverGraphAlpha": 0,
        "switchable": false,
        "valueWidth": 0
      },
      "graphs": [{
        "title": "Shielded",
        "valueField": "shieldedTemp",
      }, {
        "title": "Exposed",
        "valueField": "exposedTemp",
      }],
        "valueAxes": [{
        "title": "Ambient Temperature (°C)"
      }]
});
```

Here's the div that the graph is displayed in:

```
<div id="vDataGraphs_AmbientTemperature" style="background: red"></div>
```

And its styling:

```
#vDataGraphs_AmbientTemperature {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: -12;
  margin-top: 5;
}
```

Here's the style for the main div, where the scrolling happens:

```
.mainContainer {
  max-width: 1216;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100;
  margin-bottom: 65;
  position: center;
  padding-right: 10;
  padding-left: 10;
}
```

UPDATE: To reproduce the error, paste this code into a html file and open it (the graph will stay on the 'loading data' message):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
        AmCharts.makeChart("vDataGraphs_AmbientTemperature", {
          "type": "serial",
                "dataLoader": {
            "url": "retrieve/getReportsForDate.php?date=2017-01-01"
          },

          "theme": "default",
          "plotAreaFillAlphas": 1,
                    "plotAreaFillColors": "white",
          "autoMargins": false,
          "marginTop": 25,
                    "marginRight": 0,
          "marginBottom": 20,
          "marginLeft": 44,

          "categoryField": "timestamp",
          "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN",
                "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
                    "minPeriod": "ss",
            "tickLength": 6,
            "centerLabels": true,
            "labelOffset": -3
                },

          "allLabels": [{
            "text": "this is an Amcharts graph, and should also scroll like the text, but the Amcharts created elements do not do this (things created by me like the div containing the graph scroll fine)",
            "align": "center",
            "bold": true,
            "size": 18,
            "y": -5
          }],
                "chartCursor": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN",
                        "cursorColor": "#000000",
                        "fullWidth": true,
                        "graphBulletSize": 0,
                        "selectionAlpha": 0.3
                    },
          "balloon": {
                        "horizontalPadding": 9,
                        "pointerWidth": 15,
                        "shadowAlpha": 0
                    },
          "legend": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "horizontalGap": 22,
                        "left": 0,
                        "rollOverGraphAlpha": 0,
                        "switchable": false,
            "valueWidth": 0
                    },
                "graphs": [{
                    "title": "Shielded",
                    "valueField": "shieldedTemp",
                }, {
                    "title": "Exposed",
                    "valueField": "exposedTemp",
                }],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "title": "Ambient Temperature (°C)"
                }]
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()" style="margin: 0">
        <div style="background: blue; height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0">
            this is a fixed header, and everything in the green div should scroll 'behind' it
        </div>
        <div style="background: green; margin-top: 50">
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <div id="vDataGraphs_AmbientTemperature" style="width: 100%; height: 400; background: white; margin-bottom: -12; margin-top: 5; background: red;"></div>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
            <p>this is some text, and scrolls fine, disappearing as it goes past the boundary of the div</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What units are you using for your width/height/etc? Your CSS isn't exactly valid with missing units, so that might be worth looking at first. Outside of that, it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your CSS and markup as just using what you have doesn't trigger the issue on my end. If you can provide a fiddle or codepen that reproduces this, that would help a lot.

Comment: @xorspark I've tried that but is doesn't change anything. Please see my last code snippet, a very quick and simple illustration of the problem. Just paste it into a HTML file and open it. Why is only the graph staying above the fixed header? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an amCharts issue, it's related to how SVGs are rendered with regards to z-indexes (I double-checked a couple of other SVG-based chart libraries as well). Setting an explicit z-index on your header fixes the problem:

```
<div style="background: blue; height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 1">
    this is a fixed header, and everything in the green div should scroll 'behind' it
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k18794oe/